# How to set the TextField frame based on the image availability in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6, frame

I have a customised TableView look like following image

[image: My TableView]

My thought is in the `tableview` fourth row have no `image` that time i want to set the `label` `frame` left as equal to `image` left how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your label to be on the same left coordinates as of the imageView you can use the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 

    // do the below code after setting the image in your imageView. 

    if (imageView.image == nil) 
    {
        CGRect rectNew = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.textLabel.frame.size.width, cell.textLabel.frame.size.height);
        cell.textLabel.frame = rectNew;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have small pbm i am using custom uitableviewcell i set the frame in inside the drawRect function so frame value cannot be changed in inside cellForRowAtIndexPath function how to solve this

Comment: If you are using your custom function, in that case you should send x coordinate as a parameter in the function and accordingly set the x coordinate of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method if image is nil then set frame of imageView to `cell.textLable.`  like bellow..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    if (imageView.image == nil) {
        imageView.hidden = YES;
            cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y, setWidth, setHight);//set Hight and width of yout textlable of cell
    }
}
```

Comment: this method will set the frame of label same as that of the imageview,, which is actually not the proper answer. He only wants to set the left coordinate of the label to be same as that of the imageView.

Comment: yes this is actually what he wants to do. But @chirag Bhutani added the correct answer before you, So i voted up for him. Anyways, thanx for correcting it. Hope you can help the community with your experience. Gud luck

Comment: @SKM wel-come, if you have custom cell then property synthesize all control and then set frame in cellForRaw method.. i do this type of code in my many app..